# Can a Java program be analyzed to strip it down to essential packages as well as the JRE?

Tags: java, size, runtime, optimization

Is there some tool that can analyze a Java program and strip down the Java runtime and the program itself to the essentials only? Can a tool analyze the programs dependencies and create a custom JRE just with the required libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). They [claim](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/results.html) it also works on rt.jar from the JRE.

Answer (score 3):

You could try http://proguard.sourceforge.net/.  It allows you removed unused classes and methods.  This can backfire if you're using things like Class.forName("myclass"), so be sure to test a lot.  You could try to run the shrinker against the JVM libraries, but that seems risky.

Comment: ProGuard claims to handle `Class.forName("name")` when `"name"` is a literal (or some other thing like a final static variable that ProGuard can definitely figuer out). It's only cases like `Class.forName(variable)` where `variable` is unpredictable that will give problems.